# How to create multiple global catergories?

Tags: category, category-tree

I want to create one more category layer above root category.

for e.g:  I have three categories, MEN,WOMEN,KIDS. I want this three
as global category.  Under Men, Fashion is root category and t-shirts
is sub category.

Comment: visit the link:-http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/

Comment: in layman words, I want more then one default category. the above link can't  fulfill my requirement.

Comment: means defualt category

Answer (score 0):

If you Want Create "Men" as a Root Category. then Select Men Category after that Click On Add Subcategory Button Then Create Category Which will Subcategory of Men.

Comment: That is not my question. My question is to make more then one root category meaning more then one global categories.